# "Not enough information to infer type variable B" when calling ConfigurationBuilder.newComponent()

Tags: kotlin, log4j2

I'm trying to implement a programmatic configuration of log4j2 in my application, but when I'm calling the `ConfigurationBuilder.newComponent()` method I get the `"Not enough information to infer type variable B"` compiler error.

Here is the code snippet:

```
val builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder()
val graylogAppender = builder.newAppender("Graylog", "Gelf")
    .addAttribute("host", "tcp:localhost")
    .addAttribute("port", 12201)
    .addComponent(
        builder.newComponent("Field") // <-- Error here
            .addAttribute("literal", "some value")
    )
```

The same code in Java compiles just fine.

The signature of the `newComponent()` is:

```
<B extends ComponentBuilder<B>> ComponentBuilder<B> newComponent(String pluginName);
```

I'm new to Kotlin and not really sure how to explicitly specify the return type of the method in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the signature for `addComponent()` that it wants a `Component<?>`, so the type `B` doesn't matter. In Kotlin, when the type is unneeded or unknown, you can use `*` instead of `?` as you would in Java. So you can just use `ComponentBuilder<*>` as the return type from `newComponent`.

```
.addComponent(
    builder.newComponent<ComponentBuilder<*>>("Field")
        .addAttribute("literal", "some value")
)
```